# Transitioning into or transitioning to

Tags: prepositions

I'm having trouble writing this sentence:
"Her hair was transitioning to/into stark white due to the relentless torture."
Also, would there be a comma after white?

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic usage is "becoming stark white" or "turning stark white" Also, "due to" is an adjective. Change it to owing to, because of.  I.e., X is due to Y.